# Complete example for watermarking PDF file with text

Tags: c#, pdf

There doesn't seem to be a complete working example to create a text watermark on an existing PDF.  The examples I've located on the web seem to generate a new file or the examples I've tried do not work.

I've included some of the pages I've found below although they fail to achieve my stated goal.

[watermark article #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612044/add-image-watermark-over-another-image-in-pdf-c-sharp)

[watermark article #2](http://aspassembly.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/watermark-on-exisiting-pdf-using.html)

Please advise as I've spent literally all day on this?

**I've tried the following code (using the second watermark article link from above)**

Error received.

Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\HELLLLLOO'.

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
    [System.Web.Mvc.RoutePrefix("api/home")]
    public class HomeController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [System.Web.Mvc.Route("Index")]
        public void Index()
        {
            StampDocument.PutTextWateMark(@"myfile.pdf", "HELLLLLOO");
        }
    }

    public static class StampDocument
    {
        public static void PutTextWateMark(string path, string waterMarkTemplate)
        {
            byte[] _byte = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            byte[] _templateBye = File.ReadAllBytes(waterMarkTemplate);  // This line produces the error 
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(_byte);
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create));
            PdfContentByte content;
            PdfReader templateReader = new PdfReader(_templateBye);
            PdfImportedPage page = pdfStamper.GetImportedPage(templateReader, 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                content = pdfStamper.GetUnderContent(i + 1);
                content.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
            }
            pdfStamper.Close();
            templateReader.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Second article looks like your desired goal. It opens an existing PDF and adds a watermark for each of the pages, either text or image based.

Comment: It does although the text watermark method seems to require an image - see my code example as I've included the code within the question now.

Comment: Any ideas?  Many thanks,

Comment: Concerning your code: You apply `File.ReadAllBytes` to the second parameter of your `StampDocument.PutTextWateMark` call, "HELLLLLOO", and the error message is *"Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\HELLLLLOO'."* So, could it probably be that the template file "HELLLLLOO" simply does not exist in "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\"?